# Angular Get JSON as Map

Tags: angular, typescript

I have following JSON structure

```
{
"2019-03-27T21:00":23,
"2019-03-27T21:30":13,
"2019-03-27T21:48":20,
"2019-03-27T20:42":16
}
```

I would like to get this to a Typescript `Map<Date, number>`

I have tried declaring the map in my http call

```
this.http.get<Map<Date, number>>
```

Unfortunately this does not give me a map and calling `response.values()` is undefined on `values()`

How can I get my Json to a `Map<Date, number>`

Comment: but did you convert first object into map?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Saying that your response is of type `Map<Date, number>` won't typecast the data you receive, its just for Typescript intellisense that you are saying that the response is of type `Map<Date, number>` but your actual response is still the same.

Do this instead:

```
this.http.get<Map<Date, number>>(url).pipe(map(data) => {
    return new Map(Object.entries(data))
})
```

Comment: I couldn't get your syntax to work. Not sure what map in map(data) is. But I got it working by getting an Object from the http call and creating new Map as you showed

Comment: @isADon `map` under pipe is an `rxjs` operator, you can import it like : `import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'`. We use "map" to modify the returning Observable, https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/map.html